# How to merge columns and transpose in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, transpose

I'm working with a custom DBMS (compliant with SQL 2011 Standard), and am trying to combine multiple columns into a single column like so, but am struggling with the syntax:

Current table:

```
------------------------------------------
| ID | setting_A | setting_B | setting_C |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     ON    |    OFF    |  UNKNOWN  |
------------------------------------------
```

Desired query output:

```
------------------------------
|  ID  |  Setting  |  Value  |
------------------------------
|  1   |     A     |    ON   |
------------------------------
|  1   |     B     |   OFF   |
------------------------------
|  1   |     C     | UNKNOWN |
------------------------------
```

I've tried various IF and CASE statements, but have hit a wall.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *unpivot* with `union all`:

```
select id, 'A' setting, setting_A value from mytable
union all select id, 'B', setting_B from mytable
union all select id, 'C', setting_C from mytable
```

This assumes that  `setting_A`, `setting_B` and `setting_C` are of the same datatype (otherwise, you need conversions to align the datatypes before combining the resultsets).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a69c92ae1436203fd393f2a28aa1d54)**:

```
id | setting | value  
-: | :------ | :------
 1 | A       | ON     
 1 | B       | OFF    
 1 | C       | UNKNOWN
```